# Symfony2 :FOS:elastica populate fails for serializer with callback

Tags: symfony, serialization, elastica

I am using symfony LTS with master FOS:elastica and master jms_serializer.

### Config

```
fos_elastica:
clients:
    default: { host: %elastic_host%, port: %elastic_port% }
serializer:
    callback_class: FOS\ElasticaBundle\Serializer\Callback
    serializer: serializer
indexes:
    c_search:
        client: default
        types:
            adverts:
                mappings:
                    id:
                        type: integer
                    user:
                        type: string
                    Media:
                        type: nested
                        properties:
                            urlMedia: ~
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: WebSite\MyBundle\Entity\Advert
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~
```

### Populate

```
php app/console fos:elastica:populate
```

This command work without any problem before I added the lines below.  When I try to run "php app/console fos:elastica:populate" there is an infinite loop since I have added these lines:

```
serializer:
    callback_class: FOS\ElasticaBundle\Serializer\Callback
    serializer: serializer
```

### Troubleshooting:

After this I made a simple request (without serialize because of my problem) like this on my controller :

```
    public function testAction()
    {
        $repositoryManager = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.manager');
        $repository = $repositoryManager->getRepository('WebSiteMyBundle:Advert');
        $data = json_encode($repository->find('68200'));
        return $this->render('WebSiteMyBundle:Default:test.html.twig', array(
            'test'=> $data,
        ));
    }
```

On my result test there is like 5 empty arrays. I know the result is good since there is normaly 5 response in my raw request but I can't find the solution to show the real content if anyone have an idea.

Comment: Hi I have the same issue, did you succeed to deal with your problem ? I think the command run over and over because serializer is not well configured and make [circular references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference). I'll try to setup [exclusions](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies) and groups as the documentation says (or whisper !) [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/serializer.md)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was right in my comment, this issue was related to serializer and is quite logical.
Actually, if you do not specify anything, elastic will index every property and every relation in cascade which is a problem when having some circular references.

Here is what you could do to fix you problem :

## First, add some properties in your group :

```
<?php

namespace WebSite\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
 * Advert
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="advert")
 */
class Advert
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=55)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"elastica"})
     */
    private $title;

    ...
```

## Then, add this in your config file :

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: %elastic_host%, port: %elastic_port% }
    serializer:
        callback_class: FOS\ElasticaBundle\Serializer\Callback
        serializer: serializer
    indexes:
        c_search:
            client: default
            types:
                adverts:
                    serializer:
                        groups: [elastica]
                    mappings:
                        id:
                            type: integer
                        user:
                            type: string
                        Media:
                            type: nested
                            properties:
                                urlMedia: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: WebSite\MyBundle\Entity\Advert
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~
                        finder: ~
```

Then, you shouldn't have any circular reference and only having title property in your elasticsearch index.

Good luck.